# How to find the string other than mention via php?

Tags: php, html

How to find the string other than mention via php? For example let we suppose a string"Hello how are you?" now if i have to print the string other than "Hello".Is there is any way of doing it?

Comment: What your expected output and what your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the part of the string that containing "hello"?

```
   <?php
    $string="Hello how are you?";
    print str_replace("Hello ","",$string);
```